# Fastest way to record count using filter in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, select, count

I am using SQL Server version 2012. I have a table which has more than 10 million rows. I have to count records using a SQL filter.

My query is this:

```
select count(*) 
from reconcil 
where tenantid = 101
```

which is taking more than 5 minutes for 5 millions records.

Is there any fastest way to count records?

`Reconcil` table structure is

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[RECONCIL]
(
    [AckCode] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [AckExpireTime] [int] NULL,
    [AckFileName] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [AckKey] [int] NULL,
    [AckState] [int] NULL,
    [AppMsgKey] [nvarchar](30) NULL,
    [CurWrkActID] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Date_Time] [datetime] NULL,
    [Direction] [nvarchar](1) NULL,
    [ErrorCode] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [FGLOGKEY] [int] NOT NULL,
    [FolderID] [int] NULL,
    [FuncGCtrlNo] [nvarchar](14) NULL,
    [INLOGKEY] [int] NULL,
    [InputFileName] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [IntCtrlNo] [nvarchar](14) NULL,
    [IsAssoDataPresent] [nvarchar](1) NULL,
    [JobState] [int] NULL,
    [LOGDATA] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [MessageID] [nvarchar](25) NULL,
    [MessageState] [int] NULL,
    [MessageType] [int] NULL,
    [NextWrkActID] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [NextWrkHint] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    [NONFAERRORLOG] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [NumberOfBytes] [int] NULL,
    [NumberOfSegments] [int] NULL,
    [OutputFileName] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Priority] [nvarchar](1) NULL,
    [ReceiverID] [nvarchar](30) NULL,
    [RecNo] [int] NULL,
    [RecordID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [RelationKey] [int] NULL,
    [SEGLOG] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [SenderID] [nvarchar](30) NULL,
    [ServerID] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Standard] [int] NULL,
    [TenantID] [int] NULL,
    [TPAgreementKey] [int] NULL,
    [TSetCtrlNo] [nvarchar](35) NULL,
    [UserKey1] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [UserKey2] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [UserKey3] [nvarchar](255) NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [RECONCIL_PK] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([RecordID] ASC)
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: Create index on `tenantid`

Answer (score 1):

Unless you materialized the count, this non-clustered index on TenentID will provide better performance because it is narrower than the clustered primary key index and will scan only the matching rows:

```
CREATE INDEX idx ON [dbo].[RECONCIL](TenantID);
```

If performance of the aggregate query with this index isn't acceptable, you could create an indexed view with the count. The indexed view will provide the fastest performance for this query but will incur additional costs for storage and index maintenance for inserts and deletes. Also, queries that modify the table must have [required SET options for indexed views](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/views/create-indexed-views). Those costs may be justified if the count query is executed often.

SQL Server can use the indexed view automatically in Enterprise (or Developer) editions even if not directly referenced in the query as long as the optimizer can match the semantics of the query using the view. In lesser editions, you'll need to query the indexed view directly and specify the `NOEXPAND` hint.

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.VW_RECONCIL_COUNT
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS 
SELECT
      TenantID
    , COUNT_BIG(*) AS TenentRowCount
FROM [dbo].[RECONCIL]
GROUP BY TenantID;
GO
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX cdx ON dbo.VW_RECONCIL_COUNT(TenantID);
GO

--Enterprise Edition can use the view index automatically
SELECT COUNT_BIG(*) AS TenentRowCount 
FROM [dbo].[RECONCIL]
WHERE TenantID = 101
GROUP BY TenantID;
GO

--other editions require the view to be specified plus the NOEXPAND hint
SELECT TenentRowCount 
FROM dbo.VW_RECONCIL_COUNT WITH (NOEXPAND)
WHERE TenantID = 101;
GO
```

Comment: Thanks Dan Guzman. Create view solution is working for me. Record count 7108739 is returning within a second. I have one more question. I have to also count record on fields 1. SenderId, 2. Receiver 3. MessageId 4. SenderId and ReceiverId 5. SenderId and ReceiverId and MessageId etc. For all cases will I have to create different view?

Comment: @user2354396, separate views would provide the best possible `SELECT COUNT` performance but the maintenance and storage costs may be high. You could compromise with a unique clustered index on a view that groups by SenderId, ReceiverId, and MessageId. Then create additional non-unique non-clustered indexes on that view, one on ReceiverId and another on MessageId. Performance scanning these non-unique indexes would be better than scanning the table but worse than more specialized indexed views.

Comment: @user2354396, I should add that you should consider a non-clustered columnstore index to avoid creating separate b-tree indexes for each permutation. However, the columnstore index will make the table read-only in the SQL 2012 world so you would need to disable it while performing updates and re-enabling afterward.

Answer (score 0):

As being suggested, create an index or even partition your table by tenantId if you have so many items. This way you would have one data file per partition which increases performance.

Comment: We know very little about this table or how the OP's application works. So partitioning is at best a random guess at a solution and at worst dangerous advice.

Answer (score -3):

```
select count(tenantid) 
from reconcil
where tenantid = 101 group by tenantid ;
```

not sure but try using this.

Comment: Please test your answer and solution . you should checked your answers after post it, if you don't sure about answers, you can post comment or read help center for improve your attitude about answer questions in stack. wish you best